# Assembly run failed on SQL Server, strong name validation failed exception

Tags: .net, sql-server, rabbitmq

I am trying to create a SQL CLR that runs as a function. This has to have a dependency to the `RabbitMQ.Client.dll`. So far I have downloaded it and created an assembly on my SQL Server as follows:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [RabbitMQ.Client] 
FROM 'C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\RabbitMQ.Client.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
```

This way, I can go to my database project on VS and use the tools provided from such assembly. I created a function which should be called like this:

```
SELECT dbo.RabbitEnqueue(3)
```

However, running this returns an exception:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
>   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "RabbitEnqueue":
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'RabbitMQ.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89e7d7c5feba84ce' or one of its dependencies. Strong
>   name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)
>
> System.Security.SecurityException: Strong name validation failed.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)
>
> at UserDefinedFunctions.RabbitEnqueue(Int32 myId) .

According to the RabbitMQ website, [their assembly is strongly named](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet.html):

> The client assembly is strong named. The public key token is 89e7d7c5feba84ce and the public part of the signing key is
>
> 00240000048000009400000006020000002400005253413100040000010001008d20ec856aeeb8
>   c3153a77faa2d80e6e43b5db93224a20cc7ae384f65f142e89730e2ff0fcc5d578bbe96fa98a71
>   96c77329efdee4579b3814c0789e5a39b51df6edd75b602a33ceabdfcf19a3feb832f31d825416
>   8cd7ba5700dfbca301fbf8db614ba41ba18474de0a5f4c2d51c995bc3636c641c8cbe76f45717b
>   fcb943b5.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried `sn -vf` to verify the signature at the command-line?

Comment: I get the following: "Failed to verify assembly -- Strong name validation failed"

Comment: I was able to solve this, I had downloaded the assembly from nuget, it turns out I had to directly download the dll from their site, thanks!

Comment: @LuisBecerril post it as an answer instead of a comment then accept the answer in two days when you can. If you don't this will keep comming up to the front page as a question with no accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this, I had downloaded the assembly from nuget, it turns out I had to directly download the dll from their site which turns out to be strongly named.